# Print the lower half of a 2D Array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to figure out one of my homework assignments. I'm not looking for anyone to give me the answers, just some guidance please.

My professor gave me a 2D array that is 5x5 and wants us to print the lower triangular half of the array.

I created the array:

```
       Public static void main(String[] args) {           
       Int array1 [5][5] = {
                           {2,3,1,5}
                           {7,1,5,3,1}
                           {2,5,7,8,1}
                           {3,4,9,1,5}
       };
```

This prints the 2D Array:

```
       2 3 1 5 0
       7 1 5 3 1
       2 5 7 8 1
       0 1 5 0 1
       3 4 9 1 5
```

He wants us to print the lower triangular half though, so I believe he wants us to write a method that prints the jagged array of the 2D array, and I don't know where to start.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your print method for the whole matrix works, but you probably are supposed to print the first element of the first row, the first 2 elements of the second row, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, here you should iterate from `i = 0` to `i = 4` for rows, and `j = 4-i` to `j = 4` for columns and print out in the desired format.

Comment: Wouldn't both ranges be up to 5 because there are 5 rows and columns?

Comment: The index starts from 0. Hence 0 to 4.

Comment: What you will output is upper half of the triangle

Comment: @RakholiyaJenish It will be the lower half. Can you please explain how is it upper half?

Comment: @shruti1810 Sorry, it is not even upper half. Try looking at: [Triangular Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix)

Answer (score 0):

To print a lower triangular half, at each row (starting from 1) it should have same number of columns.

There use two nested for loops to get the lower triangular half of the array, one loop that iterates over the row and another loop that iterates through the column printing only the desired values as output.

Although I am not sure, it seems that your array declaration has also some error.